# Stop jumping in itemize (beamer)

Tags: beamer, spacing, vertical-alignment, align, itemize

## Context

Within my latest presentation I probably encountered a bug within the beamer package. Since todays screen sizes are mostly 16:9 or 16:10 I changed my setup to 16:10 ratio. While doing this I had an issue of an itemize jumping around while using it in a column setup with images. Strangely the problem disappeared when turning off the ratio option (changing back to 4:3)

## Request

Is there a comfortable solution to this problem? I tried out to use `\begin{overlayarea}{..}{..} ... \end{overlayarea}` but did not achieve the result I wanted.

## Comments for MWEs

1. With the first MWE you can reproduce the jumping error. Your **have** to put a picture, otherwise the error does not occur - for me at least.
2. The second MWE provides a semi-working solution with which I'm not satisfied, because the positioning is off. Strangely, when experimenting with the height parameter of the `overlayarea` (roundabout 0.6) I got the jumping again..
3. Lastly the third MWE provides the exact same code as the first MWE, but **without** `aspectratio=1610` and tada..the jumping is gone

## MWE with jumps

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=1610]{beamer}
\usepackage[english, ngerman]{babel}
\usetheme{Frankfurt}
\usecolortheme{beaver}
\usepackage[sfdefault,lf]{carlito}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\renewcommand*\oldstylenums[1]{\carlitoOsF #1}
\begin{document}
\section{Testsection}
\subsection{Something}
\begin{frame}\frametitle{Test}
    \begin{columns}
        \begin{column}{.5\linewidth}
            \begin{itemize}
                \uncover<1->{\item Hi}
                \uncover<2->{\item Hello}
                \uncover<3->{\item Hi again}
                \uncover<4->{\item Hi again}
                \uncover<5->{\item Hello again}
            \end{itemize}
        \end{column}
        \begin{column}{.5\linewidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{PictureOfYourChoice}<1>
            \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{PictureOfYourChoice}<5>
        \end{column}
    \end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

## MWE semi-working

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=1610]{beamer}
\usepackage[english, ngerman]{babel}
\usetheme{Frankfurt}
\usecolortheme{beaver}
\usepackage[sfdefault,lf]{carlito}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\renewcommand*\oldstylenums[1]{\carlitoOsF #1}
\begin{document}
\section{Testsection}
\subsection{Something}
\begin{frame}\frametitle{Test}
    \begin{columns}
        \begin{column}{.5\linewidth}
            \begin{overlayarea}{\textwidth}{.8\textheight}
            \begin{itemize}
                \uncover<1->{\item Hi}
                \uncover<2->{\item Hello}
                \uncover<3->{\item Hi again}
                \uncover<4->{\item Hi again}
                \uncover<5->{\item Hello again}
            \end{itemize}
        \end{overlayarea}
        \end{column}
        \begin{column}{.5\linewidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{PictureOfYourChoice}<1>
            \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{PictureOfYourChoice}<5>
        \end{column}
    \end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

## MWE without jumping but in 4:3

```
\documentclass[
%aspectratio=1610
]{beamer}
\usepackage[english, ngerman]{babel}
\usetheme{Frankfurt}
\usecolortheme{beaver}
\usepackage[sfdefault,lf]{carlito}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\renewcommand*\oldstylenums[1]{\carlitoOsF #1}
\begin{document}
\section{Testsection}
\subsection{Something}
\begin{frame}\frametitle{Test}
    \begin{columns}
        \begin{column}{.5\linewidth}
            \begin{itemize}
                \uncover<1->{\item Hi}
                \uncover<2->{\item Hello}
                \uncover<3->{\item Hi again}
                \uncover<4->{\item Hi again}
                \uncover<5->{\item Hello again}
            \end{itemize}
        \end{column}
        \begin{column}{.5\linewidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{PictureOfYourChoice}<1>
            \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{PictureOfYourChoice}<5>
        \end{column}
    \end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

## Addition (15.08.2018)

When using images of different heights, the smaller ones are pinned on the top of the `overlayarea`. Is there a way to center the images within the area?
I slightly edited your solution:

## MWE

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=1610]{beamer}
\usepackage[english, ngerman]{babel}
\usetheme{Frankfurt}
\usecolortheme{beaver}
\usepackage[sfdefault,lf]{carlito}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\renewcommand*\oldstylenums[1]{\carlitoOsF #1}
\begin{document}
\section{Testsection}
\subsection{Something}
\begin{frame}\frametitle{Test}
    \begin{columns}[onlytextwidth]
        \begin{column}{.5\linewidth}
            \begin{itemize}
                \uncover<1->{\item Hi}
                \uncover<2->{\item Hello}
                \uncover<3->{\item Hi again}
                \uncover<4->{\item Hi again}
                \uncover<5->{\item Hello again}
            \end{itemize}
        \end{column}
        \begin{column}{.5\linewidth}
         \begin{overlayarea}{\textwidth}{.5\textheight}
            \includegraphics<1>[width=\textwidth]{example-image-duck}
            \includegraphics<5>[width=\textwidth, height=.3\textheight,page=3]{example-image-duck}
         \end{overlayarea}
        \end{column}
    \end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I think in your 3rd example you are just lucky. I don't know the height of your images, but with simple test images (`example-image`) I'll get there jumping.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use `overlayarea` to prevent jumping, place it around the highest element - which in your case are the images not the itemization.

Personally I'd use top aligned frames/columns (i.e. `\begin{frame}[t]`) which prevent jumps fairly reliably.

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=1610]{beamer}
\usepackage[english, ngerman]{babel}
\usetheme{Frankfurt}
\usecolortheme{beaver}
\usepackage[sfdefault,lf]{carlito}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\renewcommand*\oldstylenums[1]{\carlitoOsF #1}
\begin{document}
\section{Testsection}
\subsection{Something}
\begin{frame}\frametitle{Test}
    \begin{columns}[onlytextwidth]
        \begin{column}{.5\linewidth}
            \begin{itemize}
                \uncover<1->{\item Hi}
                \uncover<2->{\item Hello}
                \uncover<3->{\item Hi again}
                \uncover<4->{\item Hi again}
                \uncover<5->{\item Hello again}
            \end{itemize}
        \end{column}
        \begin{column}{.5\linewidth}
         \begin{overlayarea}{\textwidth}{.5\textheight}
            \includegraphics<1>[width=\textwidth]{example-image-duck}
            \includegraphics<5>[width=\textwidth,page=3]{example-image-duck}
         \end{overlayarea}
        \end{column}
    \end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

**EDIT**

For vertically centring images of different height, I suggest a `minipage`

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=1610]{beamer}
\usepackage[english, ngerman]{babel}
\usetheme{Frankfurt}
\usecolortheme{beaver}
\usepackage[sfdefault,lf]{carlito}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\renewcommand*\oldstylenums[1]{\carlitoOsF #1}
\begin{document}
\section{Testsection}
\subsection{Something}
\begin{frame}\frametitle{Test}
    \begin{columns}[onlytextwidth]
        \begin{column}{.5\linewidth}
            \begin{itemize}
                \uncover<1->{\item Hi}
                \uncover<2->{\item Hello}
                \uncover<3->{\item Hi again}
                \uncover<4->{\item Hi again}
                \uncover<5->{\item Hello again}
            \end{itemize}
        \end{column}
        \begin{column}{.5\linewidth}%
         \begin{minipage}[t][.5\textheight][c]{\textwidth}
            \includegraphics<1>[width=\textwidth]{example-image-duck}%
              \includegraphics<5>[width=\textwidth, height=.3\textheight,page=3]{example-image-duck}%
         \end{minipage}%
        \end{column}
    \end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: your result works fine, but how can I determine the "right" value for this "magical" ratio of `\textheight` for the overlayarea?

Comment: @mgessenich The "magical" value is height of your largest element. I normally just guess some reasonable value, but if you want a precise value, you can look up the height of your images from the log file. For my images this would be `\begin{overlayarea}{\textwidth}{132.93933pt}%`

Comment: do you have any solution to center the images vertically? If I put images of different heights they get pinned to the top (of the overlayarea probably)

Comment: @mgessenich Can you make a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) with the images available in the `MWE` package?

Comment: by the way - how did you create the gif? :)

Comment: @mgessenich ImageMagick with the following options: `convert -delay 50 -loop 0 -density 100 -alpha remove document.pdf output.gif`

Comment: @mgessenich Quick hack: `\only<5>{\vspace*{.1\textheight}} \includegraphics<5>[width=\textwidth, height=.3\textheight,page=3]{example-image-duck}%`